# I downloaded through Bash in Ubuntu on Windows 10, but where do the files get saved?

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to find out, because I need to know for a project. (yes I'm new)

Commands:

```
wget https://github.com/emojicode/emojicode/releases/download/v0.5.4/Emojicode-0.5.4-Linux-x86_64.tar.gz -O emojicode.tar.gz \
&& tar -xzf emojicode.tar.gz && rm emojicode.tar.gz \
&& cd Emojicode-0.5.4-Linux-x86_64 && ./install.sh \
&& cd .. && rm -r Emojicode-0.5.4-Linux-x86_64
```

CLARITY: I need to know why Ubuntu can't connect to the network.  It says 'unable to connect to host address', which sounds like a network problem, even though my internet works fine.  I'm confused why it can't connect, and if anyone can explain that would be good.

EDIT: It seems the issue has been resolved in a different question.  Thanks for the attention, in any case.

Comment: The magic install of this https://www.emojicode.org/docs/guides/install.html

Comment: Both?  I wanted to download everything so I could use it.  I dunno if it has to be used through Ubuntu WSL or not.

Comment: so I could use *emojicode*

Comment: Turns out I didn't actually download everything.  It could be a network error, if you look at the answer by Florian Diesch.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 2):

In Windows, go to the directory

```
C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Packages\
```

There you should see a folder named something like  `CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc or CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu18.04onWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc`

And then open

```
LocalState\rootfs
```

And you should see the familiar linux directory structure.

Comment: Thanks!  This comment was very useful.  However, where is the downloads (or transfers?) in the directory root structure?

Comment: It should be in the home/<username> directory under rootfs.

Comment: Ah, thank you very much, sir.  That thing is buried!

Answer (score 2):

```
wget: unable to resolve host address
```

means that `wget` wasn't able to find the IP address for the server `github.com`. Without the IP address it can't connect to the server so noting has been downloaded. Most likely there is a problem with your network or your network settings.

As the other commands are separated by `&&` they were not executed when `wget` ended with an error. So basically nothing happened and there are no downloaded files.

Comment: That's weird.  I don't have a problem with my internet.  What network does ubuntu normally use?